# Can any Model be Modified into an "Autoregressive Model"?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

In one of Data Science classes, we were given a dataset to explore that contains medical/health information on patients and whether they missed their last doctors appointment or not (e.g. most of the patients have multiple rows in this dataset, some of them only have a single row).

```
  patient_id age gender appointment_number missed
1          1  43      M                  1      N
2          1  43      M                  2      N
3          1  44      M                  3      Y
4          1  44      M                  4      Y
5          2  21      F                  1      Y
6          2  21      F                  2      Y
7          2  21      F                  3      Y
```

We are tasked with exploring this data and building models that can help to understand and predict what factors are associated with patients being late.

When exploring this dataset, an immediate idea came to mind: **Perhaps patients that have missed previous appointments are more likely to miss successive appointments?**

What I did next was to isolate all rows in which patients at least had two rows of data - then, for each patient I created a new "lagged variable" that contains the result of their previous appointment ("missed", "attended").

```
my_data_lag <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(patient_id) %>% 
  mutate(previous_apt = lag(missed))

# in the future, remove all rows with NA
      patient_id age gender appointment_number missed previous_apt
    1          1  43      M                  1      N       <NA>
    2          1  43      M                  2      N          N
    3          1  44      M                  3      Y          N
    4          1  44      M                  4      Y          Y
    5          2  21      F                  1      Y       <NA>
    6          2  21      F                  2      Y          Y
    7          2  21      F                  3      Y          Y
```

Now, I wanted to fit a Logistic Regression for all patients in my isolated dataset using the "current appointment" as the response variable and "previous appointment along with health information (e.g. age, gender)" as covariates.

```
logistic_model <- glm(missed ~ age + gender + appointment_number + previous_apt, data = my_data, family = "binomial")
```

However, our professor warned against using this idea. Our professor mentioned that **using "lagged values of the response variable as a predictor" could seriously violate the assumptions of the regression model** - and it is better to use "Autoregressive Models" or "Longitudinal Models" for such a problem. I think the professor implied that "Autoregressive and Longitudinal Models" can incorporate lagged responses without violating model assumptions.

Although our professor did not fully explain why using "lagged values of the response variable as a predictor could seriously violate the assumptions of the regression model" (e.g. [When should we use lag variable in a regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544931/when-should-we-use-lag-variable-in-a-regression) here it says that it might not necessarily be a bad thing) - I was wondering about the second point that the professor made regarding "autoregressive models".

For instance:

- Can I somehow transform my Logistic Regression into an "Autoregressive Logistic Regression"?
- In the past, we learned about some unique types of models such as "Zero Inflated" and "Hurdle Models" - can these too be transformed into an "Autoregressive Model"? Can I transform any standard regression model into an Autoregressive Model that will thereby allow me to use lagged responses as a predictor variable?

Thanks!

Note: I was also thinking about adding a "n-1 cumulative average" variable and re-fitting the model (to account for both recent and average trends):

```
my_data_final <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(patient_id) %>% 
  mutate(cummean = cumsum(missed)/(row_number() - 1)) %>% 
  mutate(previous_apt = lag(missed))

# remove NA values
  patient_id age gender appointment_number missed   cummean previous_apt
1          1  43      M                  1      0       NaN         <NA>
2          1  43      M                  2      0 0.0000000            0
3          1  44      M                  3      1 0.5000000            0
4          1  44      M                  4      1 0.6666667            1
5          2  21      F                  1      1       Inf         <NA>
6          2  21      F                  2      1 2.0000000            1
7          2  21      F                  3      1 1.5000000            1

logistic_model <- glm(missed ~ age + gender + previous_apt + appointment_number + cummean, data = my_data, family = "binomial")
```

But I think this might result multicollinearity and jeopardize the model. I wonder if "correlated errors" could be useful here?

Comment: Autoregression literally means regressing on itself, which is when you use previous values of a time series to predict the next value(s). You can definitely use the previous outcomes of a binary response variable to predict its next in a logistic regression context. So the short answer is yes. Sorry I don't have time at the moment to give you more detailed answer.

Comment: @  Amin Shn: Thank you for your reply! I would be interested in hearing more!

Comment: Sure, maybe if you provide a chunk of your dataset (e.g. head(df) ), then I can give you a more detailed solution based on that. Btw I'll use a Bayesian approach.

Comment: @ Amin Shn: please see the update - thanks!